X++ utcdatetime and SQL
I want to perform update every Sales orders which are created after selected date in AX2009.
But X++ is so bad and it gives me an errors. Can someone can fix it? I hate this X++
static void SalesOrdersDlvMode_Update(Args _args)
{
    #define.doupdate(true)
    #define.doinfo(false)

    SysOperationProgress progress = new SysOperationProgress();
    SalesTable           salesTable;
    int                  counter = 0;
    utcdatetime          targetDate
    ;

 
    targetDate = mkDate(31, 12, 2022);

    ttsBegin;

    while select forupdate salesTable
        where salesTable.DlvMode == 'ABC'
            && salesTable.createdDateTime >= targetDate

    {
        salesTable.DlvMode = 'ABCUPD';
        salesTable.update(); // Perform the update
        counter++;
    }

    ttsCommit;

    info(strFmt("Updated: %1 records;", counter));
}


"Operand types are not compatible with the operator." STILL :(

The problem here is that targetDate type is utcDateTime but mkDate method returns date type so they are not compatible. Try the below code.
targetDate = DateTimeUtil::newDateTime(mkDate(31, 12, 2022), 0, DateTimeUtil::getUserPreferredTimeZone());

